# Do I need an approved Facebook app for Facebook share functionality in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I'd like my iOS app to have an option to share a photo on Facebook. I implemented it by following the instructions in these 2 links:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

I tested it and it works fine if I use the same Facebook account that I used for creating the Facebook app.

The problem is if I try sharing a photo with a different Facebook account, it fails. Which makes sense as the following is written on the Facebook app dashboard:

> This app is in development mode and can only be used by app admins,
>   developers and testers.

In this case, it looks like I need to switch my app to production from development. So, do I just need to enter URLs for **privacy policy** and **terms of service**? Or do I also need to start a submission for any kind of permission? Also, having a production app seems a bit vague as none of the instruction guides which are provided by Facebook itself mentions switching to production from development, they only show code pieces to use to have the share functionality.

Just to clarify, I don't use Login with Facebook, I only show `FBSDKShareDialog` for sharing photos, that's all. I don't even want to collect any information from Facebook.

Comment: Just input those two urls and take the app live

Comment: _“Or do I also need to start a submission for any kind of permission?”_ - are you _asking_ for any kind of permission in you code …? _“Also, having a production app seems a bit vague as none of the instruction guides which are provided by Facebook itself mentions switching to production from development, they only show code pieces to use to have the share functionality.”_ - that’s because those two things have very little to do with each other ...

Comment: @CBroe I don't think those two things have very little to do with each other, those code blocks are useless if I don't switch my app to live and there is no way that I could have known this before implementing and seeing that it is not working. Can you share a single page provided by Facebook which tells I need to switch my app to live to use the share functionality?

Comment: Not sure whether they actually documented something that obvious ... What the difference between a test/dev mode and “live” is, should be clear to every developer IMHO.

Comment: Ok, here you go: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/managing-development-cycle

Answer (score 0):

You will get an option App Review . Then allow  Make app Public  YES .Then any one can use it